# Get a frontpage on one side

Tags: titles

I do have a little problem. I like to make a frontpage for my thesis. In the code below I do have everything I need for that. For some reason I cannot get it on one page. I hope you see what I mean. Is there someone who may help me? I do not get it. Thanks a lot!!!

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm, footskip= 10mm} % Seitenlayout
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} % Inhaltsverzeichnis in Times

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{csquotes}             % Apostroph-Zeichen

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand 

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematik

\usepackage{multirow,array} % Auszahlungsmatrix
\usepackage{arydshln}          % vertikale und horizontale Linien in Tabelle
\dashlinegap=1pt                   % gestrichelte Linie in Tabelle

\usepackage{tikz}             % Auszahlungsmatrix

\usepackage{acronym}     % Sonstiges
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % Sonstiges

\usepackage{float} % Positionierung von Grafiken

\usepackage{caption}                 % Abbildungen/Tabellen beschriften
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=15pt} % Caption weiter unter setzen



\title{\textbf{\\Gestaltung einer Frontpage}}
\author{\\\\Seminararbeit\\am\\ Lehrstuhl für Mikroökonomie und
Empirische Wirtschaftsforschung\\Wirtschafts- und Sozialwissenschaftliche
Fakultät\\Universität Muster\\\\\\\\\\\\
vorgelegt von\\stud. rer. oec. Max Musterman\\aus Musterheim\\3. Fachsemester}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newgeometry{bottom= 30mm, left=25mm, right=25mm}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale= 16.4pt, yscale=5pt]
\draw[-] (0, -0.5) -- (1,-0.5);
\node at (0, -0.6)[right] {Seminarleitung: Prof. Dr. XY};
\node at (0, -0.7)[right] {Abgabetermin: 25. Juni 2016};
\node at (0, -0.8)[right] {Herbstsemester 2015};
\node at (1, -0.6)[left] {Anschrift des Verfassers:};
\node at (1, -0.7)[left] {Musterstrasse 1};
\node at (1, -0.8)[left] {1234 Musterhausen};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The title (`\maketitle`) finishes the page completely and starts a new one. Aside, using a figure is not what you want. And why using TikZ for a very simple list/table? And why is this question labeled {tikz-pgf}?

Comment: My standard link for title pages: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: @Johannes_B: The OP uses `tikz` after the title ;-) Isn't that justification enough? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best appropach is probably just to design a separate title page and include it with `\includepdf` or to use the `titlepage` environment to define it inline.

However, if you wanted to use `\maketitle`, you could abuse some more of KOMA's facilities to do so.

Suppose you wanted something like this:

[image: title page]

You could use something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, titlepage=firstiscover, ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} % Inhaltsverzeichnis in Times
\renewcommand\coverpagebottommargin{30mm}
\renewcommand\coverpagetopmargin{25mm}
\renewcommand\coverpageleftmargin{25mm}
\renewcommand\coverpagerightmargin{25mm}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\Large}

\usepackage{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{textcomp}             % Apostroph-Zeichen
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand

\begin{document}
\title{Gestaltung einer Frontpage}
\subtitle{%
  \vfill
  Seminararbeit\\
  am\\
  Lehrstuhl für Mikroökonomie und Empirische Wirtschaftsforschung\\
  Wirtschafts- und Sozialwissenschaftliche Fakultät\\
  Universität Muster\vfill}
\author{%
  vorgelegt von\\
  stud. rer. oec. Max Musterman\\
  aus Musterheim\\
  3. Fachsemester}
\date{}
\publishers{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{%
    \hrule
    \bigskip
    Seminarleitung: Prof. Dr. XY\hfill Anschrift des Verfassers:\par
    Abgabetermin: 25. Juni 2016\hfill Musterstrasse 1\par
    Herbstsemester 2015\hfill 1234 Musterhausen%
  }%
}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Exactly what I wanted ; ). I just have another question: May I put the thing below at the bottom of the page? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't you make the bottom margin smaller? It is currently 30mm because that's what you used in the question, so obviously, the page ends quite high up the page. If you want it to end lower down, just adjust this value accordingly. These values only affect the first page - KOMA has special facilities for this - so you can set the value to precisely the margin you want below the very last line.